# Java Grammar variable declaration production rules

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, grammar, variable-declaration

If I try to initialize a variable which is not an array using braces I get a compilation error.

E.g.:

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double a = {1.5,6.3};

    }
}
```

Using "javac", i get this compilation error:

```
test1.java:13: error: illegal initializer for double
double a = {1.5,6.3};
           ^
1 error
```

However, I am studying Java Grammar and I found the following productions (from [The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)):

```
VariableDeclarators:
    VariableDeclarator
    VariableDeclarators , VariableDeclarator

VariableDeclarator:
    VariableDeclaratorId
    VariableDeclaratorId = VariableInitializer

VariableDeclaratorId:
    Identifier
    VariableDeclaratorId [ ]

VariableInitializer:
    Expression
    ArrayInitializer

ArrayInitializer:
    { VariableInitializersopt ,opt }
```

With these rules, I can successfully compile the code above (I tried this with a compiler that uses jflex and a .cup specification file in which the grammar is specified).
Why is this possible? Is there something I ignore?

Thank you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's the grammar from the official Java Spec. I think we can assume that it is not wrong.

Comment: @sepp2k I *meant to* say OP's (not present) implementation **must** be incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, yes, the grammar *is* right, but it makes no sense.

"Pigs are flying in the sky." is a grammatical English sentence, but it does not make sense.

You have written a grammatical Java statement, but compilation failed because compilation is not just about matching the grammar, types also have to match (among lots more other things). Here, the left hand side of the `=` is a double-typed variable and the right hand side is an expression of type `double[]`. The 2 types are not implicitly convertible, so the code fails to compile.

To make it compile successfully, try changing `double` to `double[]`.

Answer (score 2):

With the grammar you can successfully *parse* your code and so can `javac` (note that `javac`'s error message does not say "[something] expected", which would be the message it produces for parse errors). But compilation involves more than parsing - it also involves type checking and when the code doesn't type check, it won't compile.

As another example the grammar also allows `int x = "lala";`. Like your example, this parses correctly, but will be rejected by the type checker.

The rules for when a program is well-typed are also part of the specification, but separate from the grammar. These rules prohibit things like `double a = {1.5,6.3};` or `int x = "lala";`.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler typically goes through three phases before accepting a program as valid: lexical, syntactic, and semantic. A piece of code that conforms to the formal grammar spec is only lexically and syntactically, but not necessarily semantically, valid. In this case it does not make semantic sense to assign a vector of values to a scalar variable, hence it is not semantically valid.